# Connections between the area of hyperbolic n-polygons and its side lengths

Tags: surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic

Is there any connection between the area of hyperbolic n-polygons and its side lengths?
I only know there is a formula connects the area of hyperbolic n-polygons with its angles
$$Area(P)=(n-2)\pi-\sum\theta(v_i)$$

Comment: Are the polygons convex?

Comment: Yes, they are convex.

Comment: How about the ["law of cosines"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_law_of_cosines)? I think this gives a partial answer when combined with your Gauss-Bonnet formula.

Comment: There is none already for quadrilaterals: One can easily construct a family of convex hyperbolic rhombi with fixed side-lengths for which the area is nonconstant.

Comment: On the other hand you can get nice answers for *regular* $n$-gons, simply by dividing them into $2n$ right triangles and then using the [hyperbolic law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_law_of_cosines) to translate between angle and edge length.